How to make ScrollView bound to its child View in SwiftUI
I want my ScrollView to dynamically adjust its size based on the content, without altering the overall view layout. Additionally, I want to be able to scroll up and down in the view (persist its position) without it bouncing back to its original position.
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var scrollViewContentSize: CGSize = .zero
    var body: some View {
        let _ = ContentView._printChanges()
        VStack {
            Text("Header")
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                        Text("IOS Dev")
                        Text("SwiftUI")
                }
                .background(
                    GeometryReader { geo in
                        Color.blue.task {
                            scrollViewContentSize = geo.size
                            print(scrollViewContentSize)
                        }
                   }
                )
            }
            .frame(width: scrollViewContentSize.width,
                   height: scrollViewContentSize.height,
                   alignment: .center)
            .background(Color.red)
            
            Text("Footer")
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

the issue is IOS DEV and SwiftUI are not visible because when i added frame modifier to scrollView, scrollViewContentSize.width is becoming zero.
Give me solution based on IOS 15 or before not later.
